# FancyBox works on local server but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I had this working on Heroku at one point. Then I went off and fixed other issues and this stopped working. I'm using Rails 4.0 and I'm lost on this. I read everything I can find on the issue. I'm not sure if there is a problem with the asset pipeline or if the issue is an actual jquery issue. Like I said, the fancybox was working on Heroku at some point and it currently works on my local server. The fancybox was just displaying one picture overlay by clicking a smaller version of it. What is happening now is that the image link is just leading me to another page where the picture is located and nothing else. The fancybox never appears. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Gemfile: https://github.com/gjarnos/depot/blob/morecss/Gemfile

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery.js
//= require fancybox
//= require jquery.ui.effect-blind
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require jquery.jcarousel.min.js
//= require jcarousel.basic.js
//= require admin
//= require carts
//= require line_items
//= require orders
//= require products
//= require sessions
//= require store
//= require users
```

Application.css.scss:

```
 *= require scaffolds
 *= require fancybox
 *= require home
 *= require admin
 *= require carts
 *= require line_items
 *= require orders
 *= require products
 *= require sessions
 *= require store
 *= require users
 *= require everythingelse
 */
```

Coffee script for fancybox:

```
jQuery ->
  $("a.box").fancybox();
```

HTML for page displaying box:

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>SHOP</h1>

<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <% cache ['entry', product] do %>
      <div class="entry">

        <%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), asset_path(product.image_url), class: "box" %>

        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <h4><%= sanitize(product.description) %><h4>
        <div class="price_line">
          <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
          <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product), remote: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Any specific errors on javascript console?

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks for the heads up. I was in fact getting an error in the console. I noticed an old JQuery code line was being used. That lead me to the real issue. I've been having issues with my asset pipeline and the production environment. My precompiled assets were pushed to my public folder on my Github repository. These assets were then pushed to heroku. As a result, my updated javascript and css aren't getting updated correctly. Heroku kept using old files that have been since updated. I need to figure out the asset pipeline more.